# Add label to a rotated doubly linked list

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have done a doubly linked list as below but I still not satisfy the label annotation of begin and end. I know it's a bad style now but don't how simplify it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\def\N{6}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  list/.style={
    very thick, rectangle split, 
    rectangle split parts=3, draw, 
    rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt,
    inner sep=5pt, text=black,
    rectangle split part fill={blue!20, red!20, blue!20}
  }, 
  ->, start chain=M0 circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*360/\N:2.5cm)},very thick
  ]    
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
    \node[list,on chain,rotate={360*\i/\N-90}] (P\i) {\nodepart{second} $P_{\i}$};
  }

  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,...,\N} {
    \ifthenelse{\i=\N} {\pgfmathsetmacro\j{1}}{}
    \path[*->,red] (P\j.three) edge [bend left] (P\i.north west);
    \path[*->,blue] (P\i.one) edge [bend left] (P\j.south east);
  }
  \draw[->,rotate=360/\N-90] ([yshift=1cm]P1.north) -- node [above,rotate=360/\N] {begin} (P1.north);
  \draw[->,rotate=-90] ([yshift=1cm]P\N.north) -- node [above,rotate=0] {end} (P\N.north);
  \draw[->,dashed] (360/\N:2cm) arc (360/\N:270:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Wish to improve:

1. Can we use a Mod to replace the ifthenelse statement?
2. The label seems need to rotate the same as the rectangle, can we just do it the same with rectangle then only need to rotate one time.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe use polar coordinate system?

Comment: If it's a problem with label annotation style, please explain what would like you? If it's a problem with your `TikZ` style, try with `\draw[<-] (P1.north) --node[sloped,above]{begin} ($(P1.north)!1.5cm!90:(P1.north east)$);` although I don't know what's wrong with your solution. It does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly what you wanted to do. Additionaly to your two points of concern I also made it scale with the number of nodes, but it becomes a giant graph pretty fast.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\def\N{11}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   list/.style=
    {   very thick, draw, minimum size=18pt, inner sep=5pt, text=black,
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, rectangle split horizontal, 
    rectangle split part fill={blue!20, red!20, blue!20}
  }, 
  ->, start chain=M0 circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*360/\N:{1.25/sin(180/\N)})}, very thick
]    
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
    \node[list,on chain, rotate={360*\i/\N-90}] (P\i) {\nodepart{second} $P_{\i}$};
  }

  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{mod(\i,\N)+1}
    \path[*->,red] (P\j.three) edge [bend left] (P\i.north west);
    \path[*->,blue] (P\i.one) edge [bend left] (P\j.south east);
  }
  \draw[->] (P1.north) -- node [above, sloped] {begin} ++ (360/\N:2cm);
  \draw[->] (P\N.north) -- node [above, sloped] {end} ++ (360:2cm);

  \draw[->,dashed] (360/\N:{1.25/sin(180/\N)*0.8}) arc (360/\N:270:{1.25/sin(180/\N)*0.8});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]